# Extended Module for Subscription Newsletter in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, newsletter

I have extend a module for subscription newsletter in magento 2 for change in NewAction.php file.
After enabling the Module it doesn't work As, i want to remove newsletter popup on subscription success.

My di.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
<preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber" type="News\Newslettermodule\Controller\Subscriber" />
</config>
```

My module.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="News_Newslettermodule" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure your module is successfully installed?

Comment: Yes it give me success message like The following modules have been enabled:

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean You want to close modal popup on success?
I will show my popup's JS, hope part of it will help you

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($, modal) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('devall.popupManager', {
        /**
         * creating popup
         */
        _create: function () {
            var self = this,
                popupOptions = {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: this.options.popupTitle,
                    buttons: false,
                    modalClass: 'popup-devnewsletter',
                    autoOpen: true,

                    /**
                     * setting a cookie
                     */
                    closed: function () {
                        self._setCookie();
                    }
                },
                contentOptions = {
                    success: this.options.successContent
                };

            if (!$.cookie('popup_cookie')) {

                if (this.options.popupEvent === 'Exit') {
                    $(document).mouseleave(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $(document).off('mouseleave');
                        modal(popupOptions, $('#popup-devnewsletter'));
                    });
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        modal(popupOptions, $('#popup-devnewsletter'));
                    }, this.options.popupDelay * 1000);
                }
            }
            this.element.find('form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).validation('isValid')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'html',
                        type: 'POST',
                        showLoader: true,

                        /**
                         * Success function
                         */
                        success: function () {
                            $('#form-div-element').remove();
                            $('#devnewsletter-validate-detail').html(contentOptions.success);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },

        /**
         * cookie function
         */
        _setCookie: function () {
            var expDate = new Date();

            expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 21);
            $.cookie('popup_cookie', 1, {
                expires: expDate
            });
        }
    });

    return $.devall.popupManager;
});
```